# What is the derivative of $\mathrm dI/ \mathrm dt$ , where $I =I_0 e^{-t/RC}$?

Tags: calculus

What is  $$\frac{\mathrm dI}{\mathrm dt}, \text{ where } I =I_0 e^{-t/RC}?$$
Any help please? Been learning derivatives for a day or two.

Comment: Do you know how to find the derivative of an exponential function?  i.e. $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \mathrm{e}^t$?  Can you use that to determine $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} C \mathrm{e}^t$ for a constant $C$?  For the constants in the exponent, are you familiar with the chain rule?

Comment: Derivative of $I$ is proportional to $I$ itself. Differentiate and find the constant.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean $\frac{dI}{dt}$ and it should actually be 
$$
I(t)=I_0e^{-t/RC}
$$
where $I_0$ is a constant (initial current?), then by the [chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) 
$$
I'(t)=I_0e^{-t/RC}(-t/RC)'=-\frac{I_0}{RC} e^{-t/RC}
$$